# AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Callable'

Tags: python, python-3.x, юнит-тесты, python-3.10

Запускал у себя тест и вернуло вот такое:

```
if isinstance(tests, collections.Callable) and not is_suite:
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Callable'
```

Как это исправить? Версия питона 3.10

Answer (score 2):

Начиная с Python 3.3 класс `Callable` (и некоторые другие классы) перенесены в модуль [collections.abc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html), в модуле `collections` остались только псевдонимы ("ярлыки") для этих классов (для сохранения обратной совместимости со старым кодом), т.е. можно было импортировать тот же `Callable` как из `collections`, так и из `collections.abc`, см. https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#collections:

> - The abstract base classes have been moved in a new collections.abc module, to better differentiate between the abstract and the concrete collections classes. Aliases for ABCs are still present in the collections module to preserve existing imports. (bpo-11085)

В Python 3.9 эти псевдонимы были сделаны deprecated (не рекомендуемые к использованию), см. https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#you-should-check-for-deprecationwarning-in-your-code,
а в версии Python 3.10 - удалены см. https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#removed:

> - Remove deprecated aliases to Collections Abstract Base Classes from the collections module. (Contributed by Victor Stinner in bpo-37324.)

Поэтому `Callable` теперь нужно импортировать из `collections.abc`:

```
from collections.abc import Callable

...

if isinstance(tests, Callable) and not is_suite:
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй скачать nose3.

```
pip install nose3 | nosetests
```

Comment: Это никак не поможет с ошибкой импорта в тесте